# On keyup in input field disappears $(event.target).attr('href')

Tags: jquery

Here https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/551094/ placed the code.

And below is the code.

Html

```
<div class="contenteditable" id="id_logo" >
<a href="https://jsfiddle.net">Some logo</a>
</div>

<div id="contenteditable_menu_ahref" style="display:none;" >
<input type="text" id="ahref_url" placeholder="Url" />
</div>

<span id="some_result"></span>
```

jquery

```
var process_href = function (event) {

event.preventDefault();
$('.contenteditable').attr("contenteditable","true");
$("#contenteditable_menu_ahref").css({'display':'block'});

$("#ahref_url").val( $(event.target).attr('href') );
$("#some_result").html( $(event.target).attr('href') );

} 
$(document).on("click", ".contenteditable", process_href);
$(document).on("keyup", ".contenteditable", process_href);
```

Doing the following:

1) Click on text `Some logo`. Opens menu with input field that contains url.

2) Click again on the text `Some logo` (somewhere in the middle), for example between the words. Then with keyboard start to type something. Url disappears from input field, but remains in `span`. Such behavior is in Chrome and Firefox. In Edge url remains.

Questions:

1) How to keep the url in input field? At the moment seems solution that i take it from `span`

2) Why such behavior. As checked console of Chrome, on `click` there is `target:a attributes` but on `keyup` can not find `target:a`, see only `target:div`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) How to keep URL in the input field?

```
var process_href = function (event) {

  event.preventDefault();
  const link = $(this).children('a').attr('href');
  $('.contenteditable').attr("contenteditable","true");
  $("#contenteditable_menu_ahref").css({'display':'block'});

  $("#ahref_url").val(link);
  $("#some_result").html(link);

} 
$(document).on("click", ".contenteditable", process_href);
$(document).on("keyup", ".contenteditable", process_href);
```

You can use `this` or `event.currentTarget` to get the element which runs the handler, in your case it is `DIV`.

`event.target` gives The most deeply nested element that caused the event.

2) Why such behavior?

This is because of event bubbling. Every child element of the `DIV` would bubble their click event up the DOM to until the DIV's click event handler catches it. Would recommend you to read this post. https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that **class="contenteditable"** was put on <*div*> element.

Just change your editable field to <*a*> tag and it will work as expected.

HTML:

```
    <div class="logo header_class" id="id_logo" >
    <a class="contenteditable" href="https://jsfiddle.net">Some logo</a>
    </div>

    <div id="contenteditable_menu_ahref" class="display_none" >
    <input type="text" id="ahref_url" placeholder="Url" />
    </div>


    <span id="result_of_activities"></span>
```

**Why such behavior in chrome ?**

*Answer :*

$(document).on("keyup", ".contenteditable", process_href);

This will find the element with the class *contenteditable* which is this case was <*div*> and call the function *process_href* which would return *undefined* for attr('href') which explains why the <*span*> element didn't change because html(undefined) wont do anything. The same works well with Click event because it is designed to get the exact element of click where the class is *contenteditable*.

Comment: @Diwya Mehta. Thanks for answer. But what if user wants part of text as link and part of text not link. And whole text must be contenteditable. Here is example https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/551334/